# Юникод ие и сафари

Tags: css

Почему символы юникода неправильно отображаються в ие и сафари?
img:http://f3.s.qip.ru/cMfvUCcf.png
Символ вставлен вот так: http://f3.s.qip.ru/cMfvUCch.png
Страница в UTF-8 без BOM

Answer (score 1):

Потому что Вы вставили уже изображение символа, а не Unicode. В Unicode этот символ выглядит как `&#x2713;`